# Mysql Db sync options

Tags: mysql, replication, database-replication

Question on MySQL replication (mainly).

So I have 2 MySQL databases, which are identical schema, but not connected by a network of any kind.  I need one-way (only) syncing of data, i.e. Db1 always needs to copied/dumped down, and synced with Db2 . There is update/insert/delete activity on both.

I have ensured that DB2 (which is the receiver, always) has sequences in a very high range - so records created on or 'owned' by DB2 won't conflict with DB1 records when synced. There is also a rule that down on DB2, we won't edit any data that was created on DB1 (we can tell by the sequence number, but also by the kinds of data being inputted on each DB).

I've already got this working via a mysqldump (from Db1), and modifying the dump to have "REPLACE INTO" instead of "INSERT into" - and running this modified mysqldump-output as a SQL script. Volumes are not too high, works fine.

Is it possible to do this (simply enough) via replication. Mysql can create snapshot dumps, and I would copy them over and run a replication command - is that feasible.

Answer (score 1):

1. I would use `auto_increment_increment` & `auto_increment_offset` to make sure the records don't overlap. I know you said you set the records on DB2 to a high range, but *eventually* they may still overlap. Just making DB1 use odd values and DB2 use even values makes sure that will never happen.
2. You can't use replication, if the two instances are not connected by a network. Replication requires that the replica is able to make a connection to its master.
3. But you can use binary logs, which is one part of how replication works. On DB1, enable binary logging, which will record every change made to the database. Periodically, copy these logs to the server for DB2 (I assume you have some way of doing this if you're currently using mysqldump). Use the `mysqlbinlog` tool to convert the logs into SQL commands to replay against your DB2 instance.

   Example:

   ```
    mysqlbinlog binlog.000001 binlog.000002 | mysql -u root -p
   ```
4. It's up to you to keep track of which binlogs you have copied and executed. Just before you copy a set of binlog files, run `FLUSH LOGS` on DB1. This causes DB1 to close the binlog file it's currently writing to, and open a new binlog file. This way you can work with whole files at a time without worrying about partial files.